# How to normalise a table which can link to one or more tables?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

I was wondering if someone can help me with a normalisation issue I am facing, when trying to create a seperate communication table, for a personal project I am working on. Lets say I have the following tables and table columns:

---

**Table A:**

Table_A_Id, Date, Name, Agent_Id (FK), Notes

**Agent Table:**

Agent_Id, Date, Name, Phone, Email, Notes

**Direct Contact Table**:

D_C_Id, Date, Name, Phone, Email, Notes

---

Above is a sample of my actual tables, but describes my issue.

Essentially to normalise the above table to 1NF, I need to split the Notes column into its on seperate table, to help make the tables atomic, and comply with the 1NF rules. I want to split it out to a seperate column called **Communication Table**, which can allow me to keep track of when I made a conversation relating to the respective table and what I discussed.

I am not sure how to best to handle the split out **Communication Table**. because the Notes in Table A also links to an Agent from within the table, however the Notes column in the Agent table, only relates to communications done with the Agent.

So which of the following would you recommend is best for communication table:

### EXAMPLE 1:

**COMMUNICATION TABLE**

Com_Id, Date, Link_Table, Link_Table_Id, Notes

- Here the Link_Table should define what specific table is being dealt with and Link_Table_Id is the specific Id on the Link_Table

**UPDATE:**

Sorry I forgot, I need to also add another column called **Communicated_With** to the above, because there may be instances where communication related to Table A, could occur with another agent or person.

So the table would look like:

Com_Id, Date, Link_Table, Link_Table_Id, Communicated_With, Notes

OR

### EXAMPLE 2:

**COMMUNICATION TABLE**

Com_Id, Date, Table_A_Id, Agent_Id, D_C_Id, Notes

- Here all the unrelated Id columns would have to be set to null, whilst the related colum defined with an Id.

OR

### EXAMPLE 3:

**COMMUNICATION TABLE**

Com_Id, Date, Notes

- Here all other tables have a foreign key to this table. (However, this may force me to repeat the rest of the columns just to identify its a different column).

### **UPDATE 2**

Thought of a new solution, after reviewing some youtube videos, I noticed that maybe a join table may work.

### **EXAMPLE 4**

**COMMUNICATION TABLE** (Same as Example 1, without the "Comminicated_With" Column)
Com_Id, Date, Link_Table, Link_Table_Id, Communicated_With, Notes

COMM_AGENT_JOIN TABLE
com_Id, Agent_Id

- I feel this may work, because it would allow me use the Link_Table, and Link_Table_Id to match the table being represented, and then finally the COMM_AGENT_JOIN_Id, can be used to specify which agent was communicated with, when the Link_Table is linked to Table_A.

Sorry if the answer is straight forward, I last did normalisation 2 years ago, and therefore have been struggling to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your tables. What is your database about? What is an A? A client? What do the tables have dates for? What is a direct contact? Contact of what? The contacts have nothing to do with the agents or the clients? What do they represent?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner My Tables are straight forward, Table A, is used to highlight the specific details for a service offered via an agent or the service provider directly. Although I call it dates, I really mean date time, and I am would use it to keep track of when an event occured. The comments table should help me identify all the notes made regarding a particular service that the user has signed up to (Table A) OR general notes are made when directly communicating with agent or service provider about a particular service. Hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner so the Direct Communication Table represents a direct service provider, without having an agent as a middle man.

Comment: Okay, so there are certain services. (I don't see a service table, though. Or is table A the service table?) Then some services are done by a service provider and some by an agent. (The agent works for service providers, but you are not interested in this in your database.) BTW: Why is it important for you to know whether you are dealing with a service provider or agent? What's the big difference between them? Anyway, we know who offers a service. But there should also be a client taking the service, no? Or is this always the same person or company, so you don't have to model this?

Comment: Then to the dates: "When an event occurs"? An agent isn't an event; a service provider isn't either. So what are the dates for? And what are the notes actually? The A notes are correspondences of someone with an agent? Who? The agent notes are also correspondences? Or notes about an agent? Or notes an agent made? Or what else? Anyway, I think my main question still is: what is an "A"?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Apart from "date" in the communication table and Table A, please ignore the other dates, yes an agent is not an event, but having a date there, lets me know when the agent was added to the table. The user himself is the client for the agent or service provider, and this databse is to help him keep track of his communication and subscribed services. Table A is a table which records all the services the User/ Client has taken from an agent or directly from a service provider. The notes columns will be used to note down anything important about a conversation or event.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner in regards to no service table, I havent included it to make my question easier to understand, because as I mentioned I am still trying to properly normalise it in 1NF and currently the name and package of a service is just within Table A (I simply havent mentioned the column names on the example), which I believe will be then normalised in 2NF. Review the schema Ajay has created in his answer below, that may help make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to be an answer on how to put the tables into 1NF. I hope it will be helpful, though.

When creating a database, we usually don't think in 1NF, 2NF etc. We think about what to model and what entities there are. When we think this through, then very often the database is already in 5NF or so. If in doubt we can use the NFs as a kind of checklist.

I don't know your exact requirements, so there is a lot of guessing or just general advice here. Maybe one of your problems is that you are using the noun "notes" which doesn't describe exactly what this is about. Later you call this "correspondence", but are all "notes" = "correspondence"?

Your database is about services you take from an agent or from a service company directly. So one entity that I see is this provider:

**provider**

- provider_id
- name
- contact_person_name
- phone
- email
- type (agent or final service provider)

If a provider can have multiple contacts, phones and emails, you'd make this a provider_contact table instead:

**provider**

- provider_id
- name
- type (agent or final service provider)

**provider_contact**

- provider_contact_id
- name
- phone
- email
- provider_id

As to notes: well if there are notes on a provider ("Always ask for Jane; she's the most professional there.") or contact ("Jane has worked in London and Madrid."), I'd usually make this just one text column where you can enter whatever you like. You can even store HTML or a Word document. No need for multiple documents per provider, I suppose.

Now there are also services. Either you need a list of who offers which service, then add these tables: `service` (which services exist) and `provider_service` (who provides which service). But maybe you can do without that, because you know what services exist and who provides them anyway and don't want to have this in your model.

I don't know if you want to enter service enquiries or only already fixed service contracts. In any case you may want a `service_contract` table either with a status or without.

**service_contract**

- service_contract_id
- provider_id (or maybe provider_contact_id?)
- service (free text or a service_id referencing a service table)
- valid_from
- valid_to

Here again you may have notes like "We are still waiting for the documents. Jane said, they will come in March 2018.", which again would be just one column.

Then you said you want the correspondence, which could be an additional table `service_contract_correspondance`:

**service_contract_correspondance**

- service_contract_correspondance_id
- service_contract_id
- type (received from provider or sent to provider)
- text

But then again, maybe you can do without it. Will you ever have to access single correspondances (e.g. "give me all correspondences from December 2017" or "Delete all correspondances older than one year")? Or will there be thousands of correspondences on a single contract? Mabe not. Maybe you can again see this as one single document (text, HTML, Word, ...) and add this as a mere field to the table.

Having a text consisting of multiple contacts like

```
January 2, 2018 Jane
She says they'll need to weeks to make an offer.

January 20, 2018 
I asked about the status. Talked with some Thomas Smith. He says they'll call us tomorrow.

January 21, 2018 Jane
She has emailed the contract for us to sign.
```

is not per se against NF1. As long as you are not interested in details in your database (e.g. you'll never select all January correspondence alone on the contract), then to the database this is atomic; no need to change this.

Same with contacts. If you have a string column only with "Jane (sales person) 123-45678 jane@them.com, Jack (assistent) 123-98765 jack@them.com", this is not per se against NF1 again. As long as you don't want to select names only or check phone numbers, but always treat the string as a whole, as *the* contact, then just do so.

You see, it all boils down to what exactly you want to model and how you want to work with the data. Yes, there are agents and direct providers, but is the difference between the two so big that you need two different tables? Yes there is a chronology of correspondence per contract, but do you really need them separated into single correspondencies in your database?

Comment: @ThornstenKettner Wow!!.. Thank you so much for all the effort you put into this to help me. Sorry, but the reason I gave out pre-prepared example solutions was simply because I wasnt sure which of the example I need to pick. The thing is, I did not want to disclose the actual database I am working on and therefore tried to make up the services table above, which resembled closely with the one I am developing, therefore many of your normalised solutions may need to be incorporated seperately. However I have learn an important lesson from you....

Comment: @ThornstenKettner The lesson I learnt is that I should rely on the 1NF, 2NF and 3NF to normalise, but should instead start by normalising, the data that I know requires to be seperated onto their own table and then check at the end whether if it complies with the 1NF, 2NF, 3NF... rules.Thank you very much, and I think using your advice, I will try and normalise the database using my own initiative and then test to see if it conforms to the rules.

Comment: I'm glad to hear this. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Example 3 where we store Comm_Id, Date, Notes. We need to add Comm_Id in all the three parent tables instead of Notes.

[image]

Example 1 & 2 are doing same with extra columns (duplicating information, also called [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization)). I would use these approaches when querying while joining these tables is taking more time.

Comment: wow thank you very much for the extremely detailed answer, and taking the time to create the Schema, just to express your answer. I have been considering Example 3, however, to achieve Example 3, means I must repeat all the rest of the columns inorder to differentiate the comments and therefore thought it may not be the best solution, when attempting to normalise, becuase I am repeating alot more to differentiate one column.

Comment: Hello, I just thought of another approach, I would really appreciate it if you could view Example 4, which i added to the main question, and could let me know if that would work better?. Thank you.

Comment: Here, you can store only one communication (comm_id) per whatever table A represents (one comm_id per row in Table_A. That's the problem; that's not the solution.